# Rails 6+: order in which Rails reads SECRET_KEY_BASE (env var versus credentials.yml.enc)

Tags: credentials, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ruby-on-rails-6

For context, I'm in the process of updating a Rails app to 5.2 and then to 6.0.

I'm updating my credentials to use the `config/credentials.yml.enc` and `config/master.key` defaults with Rails 5.2+ apps.

The [Rails docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage) state:

> In test and development applications get a secret_key_base derived from the app name. Other environments **must use a random key** present in `config/credentials.yml.enc`
>   (emphasis added)

This leads me to think that in production the `SECRET_KEY_BASE` value is **required** to be read from `Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base` via `config/credentials.yml.enc`.  In `test` and `development` environments, the `secret_base_key` is essentially "irrelevant", since it's calculated from the app name.

However, when I was looking at the [Rails source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/32b99f9358b828daf16236695d041288e4b2f648/activesupport/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb#L39), it reads:

```
def key
  read_env_key || read_key_file || handle_missing_key
end
```

That seems to say the **order** of reading values is:

1. `ENV["SECRET_BASE_KEY"]`
2. `Rails.application.credentials.secret_base_key`
3. Raise error

I use Heroku for my hosting, and have a `ENV["SECRET_BASE_KEY"]` env variable that stores this secret value.

**Questions**

1. If I have **both** `ENV["SECRET_BASE_KEY"]` and `Rails.application.credentials.secret_base_key` set, which one takes priority?
2. Is using the ENV var going to be deprecated at some point?
3. I have lots of environment-specific ENV variables because I don't want to use my production accounts in development for AWS S3 buckets, stripe accounts, etc.  The flat-file format of `credentials.yml.enc` seems to assume developers only need to access these 3rd-party APIs in production. Is there an accepted format to handle environment-specific credentials yet in Rails?

I read through the comment threads on DHH's [original PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/30067) as well as a [linked PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33521) that says it implements environment-specific credentials, but the docs don't mention this implementation so I'm not certain if it's the standard or if it's going to go away sometime soon.